# Woocommerce - My account -Add Payment Method not working

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am confused why the `$_POST(gateway-id-card-number)` and the expiry and CVV are not getting posted from the form in the my-account page?

The checkout form is generated by `$this->form` as per https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Payment_Gateway_CC.html

The same form is in my account page but does not work. 
The post happens in the checkout page but the in my account page the post does not happen.

The error that shows up is that all the fields submitted to the post are empty. Please help

Similar problem : 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-tokenization-developing-a-custom-gateway/

Answer (score 0):

if someone having problems with this

```
/**
     * Output field name HTML
     *
     * Gateways which support tokenization do not require names - we don't want the data to post to the server.
     *
     * @since  2.6.0
     * @param  string $name Field name.
     * @return string
     */
    public function field_name( $name ) {
        return $this->supports( 'tokenization' ) ? '' : ' name="' . esc_attr( $this->id . '-' . $name ) . '" ';
    }
```

Comment: This answer is unclear, is this a function that needs to be modified? a hook? what is this block of code and how do you apply it to fix the problem at hand?

Comment: @ZacharyCraig This block of code is from the woo commerce core. This does not solve my problem but the woocommerce default form is not going to allow data to be posted.  So I can tweak the code if i wanted to with the filter. Maybe my approach is wrong. I am still confused with the add_payment_method and how does it save the credit card.